# Chrome changed resolution after a crash

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, resolution

my Chrome crashed for some reason and after a start-up it appears like in a different resolution. Ugly fonts, large icons, etc. As a "plus" the tabs overexceed the maximum size allowed by the general window size. So i can't see them at all (and close them by clicking on the "x") as far as they just don't fit. I'm running WIN7 64-bit. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using one of the Beta or Dev releases?

Comment: It seems to be a bug, but just this fixes my issue: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1284b32b48f44aaf&hl=en

Comment: control panel-->appearance & personalization-->Make text and other items larger or smaller (under display)-->set to something 125% or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

After getting [this](https://superuser.com/a/822449/162573) answer to a different question, I noticed that a part of the solution involved a command that sets the browser's resolution right.

So, try this:

- create an icon for the browser
- right click on it - Properties, and add at the end of Target entry `/high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1`, leaving a space after what is already there

[image]

- Apply and start the browser using this icon. Other icons will not use this setting

Comment: Now I see this was already posted here: http://superuser.com/a/803650/162573