# Win8.1 x64 Chrome fonts look terrible all of sudden?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I've noticed this problem a few days ago. Chrome started displaying all fonts with a smaller space between them, has anyone had this problem?

I made a comparison screenshot with Firefox 32, the lower bar is with Chrome 37

[image]

The font settings in Chrome are default, my zoom is 100%. Other browsers and software don't have this problem.

Edit: I'm having not font size issues, but letter spacing problems..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text size suddenly got bigger on all sites on Google Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/803601/text-size-suddenly-got-bigger-on-all-sites-on-google-chrome)

Comment: Try [disabling DirectWrite](http://superuser.com/questions/803637/how-to-disable-directwrite-in-google-chrome-37).

Comment: It turns out enabling it did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling DirectWrite did the trick for me