# Chrome GUI is too big as of 43.0.2357.124-1

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts, linux-mint, scaling

Last night, I updated my version of Google Chrome from 43.0.2357.81-1 to 43.0.2357.124-1. The most visible change is that the UI elements are way too large. Here's a comparison with Chrome (top), Firefox (center) and my system fonts (bottom); only Chrome is wrong:

[image: Chrome is way too big, Firefox and vim are correct]

This isn't a page zoom issue. Chrome thinks my zoom is at 100%. I can shrink the page elements by zooming out, but the UI is still too large.

I can fix this by launching Chrome with the `--force-device-scale-factor` flag. However, this isn't really a great fix; I'd have to change my launcher shortcuts *and* any programs that launch Chrome (e.g., web servers that auto-launch a browser, like Racket's). Using this flag also causes Chrome to start with a very small window size.

I checked in `chrome://flags` and didn't see anything interesting matching the grep for "scale."

If relevant, my desktop environment is Cinnamon on Linux Mint 17.1 64-bit. My screen resolution is 1920×1080, on a normal 14-inch (157 dpi) display.

Comment: The following is a possible [duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/803601/text-size-suddenly-got-bigger-on-all-sites-on-google-chrome).  This bug report might also be [related](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=403302)

Comment: You should rollback to the [previous version](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=490880&q=UI%20font&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) to fix this.  This [submitted](https://i.imgur.com/PhJ2Q8x.png) image matches your problem exactly.  [suspected](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=473089) duplicate bug report.

Comment: there's a bug for this and the Chrome team is currently working on it. Thanks for reporting it! https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=498426

Comment: So how did it go? Do you still have this problem with the latest Chrome version? Or you stuck with an outdated software for the time being? If Chrome is the only problem, and you already have Firefox installed on the system, why not just use Firefox? Forget about Chrome! At least until they sort out the issue, then you can come back if you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ramhound suggested in a comment, I've rolled back to the previous version. Luckily, I still had the package in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, so I just installed it with `sudo dpkg -i`.

If anyone else is looking for the package, I've hosted it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i20vopi4tkkvngn/google-chrome-stable_43.0.2357.81-1_amd64.deb?dl=0). This is version 43.0.2357.81-1, as provided by the Google PPA, with no modifications.

As mentioned in the comments, this is now a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=498426), so should be fixed in some new release.

Comment: Be sure you accept your own answer.  You might mention the bug report in your answe though.  Best solution until the next release.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the reminder (there's a delay before you can accept your own answer).

Comment: Don't forget to killall chrome processes for the change to apply. I actually suspect that killall alone may fix the problem.

Comment: @JohnRos Well, a system reboot didn't fix the large GUI. But yes, a killall/reboot was required *after* the downgrade.