# How to start Chrome without plugins?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, plugins, safe-mode

I have created a separate question [Google Chrome completely unresponsive](https://superuser.com/q/822415/162573) on the problem that may be fixed in this way.

The browser cannot open any page, not even the settings, plugins and addons pages.

Using the incognito window has the same problem, maybe because some plugins are still used (or loaded).

I think addons are userprofile-specific, as indicated in [the solution](https://superuser.com/a/255018/162573) to the question [How to open Google Chrome with extensions disabled / turned off?](https://superuser.com/q/254579/162573) indicated as the one to which this may be a duplicate.

Therefore, I need to try to start with no plugins (and this one is no duplicate).

Is it possible to start Chrome in safe mode or something so that no addons or plugins are used?

(I mean start the browser already with all those disabled, because, as presented in the other question linked above, I cannot access settings nor plugins because **NO** window works, **NOT EVEN** Settings (chrome://settings/), About Google Chrome (chrome://chrome/) or Downloads (chrome://downloads/)!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open Google Chrome with extensions disabled / turned off?](http://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off)

Comment: @DavidPostill - that is about addons: I am asking about plugins too

Comment: @DavidPostill: also, [that answer](http://superuser.com/a/255018/162573) says to go to  User Data folder (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default) that is to the Default profile. That is related to a certain profile. My problem affects all profiles, which maybe means it's something not related to addons, but to plugins.

Comment: "This question may already have an answer here: [How to open Google Chrome with extensions disabled / turned off?](http://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off). It has NOT.

Comment: Out of curiosity, now you have accepted the answer from @DavidPostill, could you let us know if Chrome now works and which plug-in was at fault?

Comment: @AFC - I have edited the main question on my problem and specified that this answer although instructive and accepted here was not a solution to the other question. I also tried other things like deleting the folder %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data (all profiles and settings etc) and reinstalling, to no avail. Canary works though, as  does Chromium

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Source [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

> --disable-extensions **Disable extensions**.
>
> --disable-plugins **Prevent plugins from running**

You might also find the following useful:

> --debug-plugin-loading **Dumps extra logging about plugin loading to the log file**

**How to add these options to a Chrome shortcut**

[image]

- Right click on your Chrome shortcut
- Select Properties.
- Add to the end of the Target field --disable-extensions --disable-plugins

It will look like:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1 --disable-extensions --disable-plugins

- Click on OK
- Start Chrome.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Chrome 68, Windows 10.

Comment: I am looking to do this on Ubuntu if anyone knows how.

Comment: @MrCholo (Sorry for imprecise instructions because I have Kubuntu not Ubuntu) Right click your Chromium (or Chrome) somewhere (like Applications menu) and choose edit application or properties or open with gedit. There should be a line like `chromium-browser` which you would change to `chromium-browser --disable-extensions --disable-plugins`.

Comment: That doesn't work. I call `./chrome --disable-extensions` from bash and it launches with extensions enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Create a .bat file

```
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe 
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe
taskkill /F /IM googleupdate.exe
taskkill /F /IM outwit-hub.exe

start chrome --disable-extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command line option `--disable-plugins` to disable plug-ins.

Other possible solutions to the apparent problem are rebooting your system, clearing your browser cache, running an anti virus system check, attempting an update, attempting an installation repair (if Chrome has that feature), and doing a full uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: already did reinstall, no use