# Web pages taking very long time to load

Tags: windows, browser

About 50% of the time, webpages are taking a very long time to load in any browser on my desktop machine. In chrome, I eventually get the [kill pages error](https://cdn.xtremerain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/kill_pages__by_smosh_4evrr-d51xins.png). The other 50% of the time, they load very quickly as we have a pretty decent connection speed.

It's not the router or ethernet cable. I've tested out multiple wired and wireless devices and it only seems to occur with my desktop machine.

At idle, my Physical Memory usage is at about 34% and once a browser is open, it's at about 50%.

I've scanned my machine multiple times so I don't think it's a virus or any malware.

It's only began in the last two months.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to what else might be causing this?

[image]

*One interesting thing - it's never happened with uTorrent turned off, but it has and has not happened with uTorrent turned on.*

Comment: Have you tried to start the browser (e.g. firefox) in Safe Mode, have you tried to disable all AddOns?

Comment: @duDE no I havn't tried Safe Mode. I have no add-ons or extensions at all for firefox and only a few extensions in Chrome, but I'll disable and uninstall them all and try that out, thanks.

Comment: Possibly related : [How to start Chrome without plugins?](http://superuser.com/questions/822429/how-to-start-chrome-without-plugins)

Comment: If it is only the first time that they load slow then it might be stuck on DNS lookups.

Comment: @Hennes no, it's sort of a constant thing. I can refresh or wait until one page loads and then open a few more tabs on with the same address and it's the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One interesting thing - it's never happened with uTorrent turned off,
>   but it has and has not happened with uTorrent turned on.

Your GET requests are most likely getting queued behind large uploads from uT. With many residential connections you may have 20Mb down but only 1 or 2Mb upload, so having a P2P client running can cause sporadic issues. Set uTs upstream limit to 50% of your upstream bandwidth.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks a lot. But I've 100mb down, can't remember off hand what I have up though. Regardless, I'll definitely test this out.

Comment: @Daft The other issue can be if the cable gateway provided by the ISP cant handle large numbers of simultaneous connections and starts to chug, not uncommon either.

Comment: Cable getaway? I don't recognise that term. But it did start around the same time we we switched to a new ISP

Comment: Router + Modem = Home Gateway, "Cable Gateway" is kind of a butchering of the term that I shouldnt really have used.

Comment: This did the trick!! Much appreciated! I was preparing to throw my machine out the window 