# How do I find out which tab is crashing chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

On occasion Chrome gets into a snit and will crash.  Restart. Restore.  I have about 20 seconds to a minute and it will crash again.

Typically I will see a whirling beach ball for  15 to 100 seconds before the crash.

I get the usual crash report with a trace but it may as well be written in Basque or Navaho.

Restore works.  Brings back all my tabs.

Running Activity Monitor there is no memory pressure.  Also the raft of Chrome helpers don't look odd.   Right now after a round of this, I have 40 tabs open in three windows, with 4.4% CPU utilized.

At this point my only recourse is to use my 'one minute until you die' to close individual tabs, starting with the most recent.  Since I often have 3 windows open with 20 tabs each, this takes a while.

Starting Chrome with all extensions disabled doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is there a better way to find out what is upsetting Chrome?

Comment: This could be the plot for Source Code 2...

Comment: If a single tab is crashing, Chrome itself will not crash. Chrome is designed from the ground up to not fail based on issues in a single tab. The issue is more likely to be an addon or plugin, based on your symptoms. So I would spend that minute removing plugins and addons.

Comment: Just wanted to second the above, I've only ever seen this behaviour with extensions, so it could be effective to disable all of those and then re enable one-by-one until you find the culprit.

Comment: It's possible to start Chrome without any add-ons or extensions... https://readwrite.com/2010/02/08/extensions_broke_your_browser_how_to_enter_safe_mo/    https://superuser.com/questions/822429/how-to-start-chrome-without-plugins

Comment: I've tried starting without extensions.  Makes no difference.